# how to add elements of a list to elements of a row in pandas database

Tags: python, pandas

i have this database  called db in pandas

```
 index     win  loss  moneywin  moneyloss
player1     5     1       300        100
player2    10     5       650        150
player3    17     6      1100       1050
player11  1010   105     10650      10150
player23  1017   106    101100     101050
```

and i want to add the elements of list1 to the elements of db

```
list1 = [[player1,105,101,10300,10100],[player3,17,6,1100,1050]]
```

so the results would be db2

```
index     win   loss   moneywin  moneyloss
player1   110    102   10600      10200
player2    10     5     650         150
player3    34     12    2200       2100
player11  1010   105   10650      10150
player23  1017   106   101100    101050
```

how can i go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Create a dataframe from `list1` then `concat` it with the given dataframe then group by `index` and aggregate the remaining columns using `sum`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=df.columns)
df_out = pd.concat([df, df1]).groupby('index', sort=False).sum()
```

**Solution 2:**

Create a dataframe from `list1` then `add` it with the given dataframe using common `index`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=df.columns)
df_out = df.set_index('index').add(df1.set_index('index'), fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

           win  loss  moneywin  moneyloss
index                                    
player1    110   102     10600      10200
player2     10     5       650        150
player3     34    12      2200       2100
player11  1010   105     10650      10150
player23  1017   106    101100     101050
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it's exactly what i wanted, but it brought another question... what if i wanted to do a complicated math formula instead of simply adding the two elements, like average or variance or some other formula? Is there a predetermined function like add or is there a way to customize what i want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `add` after create the columns

```
s = pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=df.columns).set_index('index')
df = df.set_index('index')
df = df.add(s,fill_value=0)
df
Out[108]: 
             win   loss  moneywin  moneyloss
index                                       
player1    110.0  102.0   10600.0    10200.0
player11  1010.0  105.0   10650.0    10150.0
player2     10.0    5.0     650.0      150.0
player23  1017.0  106.0  101100.0   101050.0
player3     34.0   12.0    2200.0     2100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [['player1','105','101','10300','10100'],['player3','17','6','1100','1050']]

df.append(pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=df.columns)).sort_values(by=['index'])

     index   win loss moneywin moneyloss
0   player1     5    1      300       100
0   player1   105  101    10300     10100
3  player11  1010  105    10650     10150
1   player2    10    5      650       150
4  player23  1017  106   101100    101050
2   player3    17    6     1100      1050
1   player3    17    6     1100      1050
```